# Python Google Contacts API - Deleting contacts

Tags: python, gdata, google-contacts-api

Reading the Developer's Guide I found how to delete single contact:

```
def delete_contact(gd_client, contact_url):
  # Retrieving the contact is required in order to get the Etag.
  contact = gd_client.GetContact(contact_url)

  try:
    gd_client.Delete(contact)
  except gdata.client.RequestError, e:
    if e.status == 412:
      # Etags mismatch: handle the exception.
      pass
```

Is there a way to delete all contacts?
Could not find a way to do so.

Iterate each contact takes few minutes for a large batch

Comment: If you can fetch all contacts using the api, you can iterate over the all contacts and pass it to the delete_contact function.

Comment: It takes about 9 minutes to delete 1000 contacts. I was looking for a faster solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing a lot of operations, use the batch requests. You can have the server perform multiple operations with a single HTTP request. Batch requests are limited to 100 operations at a time. You can find more information about batch operations in the [Google Data APIs Batch Processing documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/batch).

To `delete all contacts` use the contactsrequest.Batch operation. For this operation, create a `LIST<type>`, you set the `BatchData` for each contact item, and then pass the list to the contactsrequest.Batch operation.

```
private void DeleteAllContacts()
{
RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(this.ApplicationName, this.userName, this.passWord);
rs.AutoPaging = true // this will result in automatic paging for listing and deleting all contacts
ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
List<Contact> list = new List<Contact>();
int i=0;
foreach (Contact c in f.Entries)
{
c.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData();
c..BatchData.Id = i.ToString();
c.BatchData.Type = GDataBatchOperationType.delete;
i++;
list.Add(c);
}
cr.Batch(list, new Uri(f.AtomFeed.Batch), GDataBatchOperationType.insert);
f = cr.GetContacts();
Assert.IsTrue(f.TotalResults == 0, "Feed should be empty now");
}
```

Comment: That might be a perfect solution for me - Is the gdata client for python support batch? I couldn't find it there.

Comment: check this [one](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/client-libraries)